Prove in K modal logic $\square p , \neg \square q \vdash_K \neg \square (p \rightarrow q) $
I need to prove in K modal logic the following
$\square p , \neg \square q \vdash_K \neg \square (p \rightarrow q)$
$1. \square p \qquad premise$
$2. \neg \square q \qquad premise$
$3. \square (p \rightarrow q)  \qquad assumption$
$4. \square (p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow (\square p \rightarrow \square q)  \qquad axiom\,K$
$5. \square p \rightarrow \square q  \qquad modus\,ponens\,3\,and\,4$
$6. \square q \qquad modus\,ponens\,1\,and\,5$
$7. \bot \qquad contradiction\,2\,and\,6$
$8.  \square (p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow \bot \qquad THD$
$9. \neg \square (p \rightarrow q) \qquad RAA\,from\,8$
$ 10. \square p , \neg \square q \vdash_K \neg \square (p \rightarrow q) \qquad THD$
THD = Theorem of Deduction
K modal logic accepts N and K axioms.
$X \rightarrow \square X \qquad N\,axiom$
$\square(X \rightarrow Y) \rightarrow (\square X \rightarrow \square Y) \qquad K\,axiom$
So I have proved the theorem.
Is there any other way to prove this?
Could you please tell me which pdf available books have a lot of problems similar to this?
Where can I practice these problems?
I have searched internet a lot, but I couldn't find a single book that has problems of this kind of nature.

That is not the axiom of necessitation. Rather: $X$ being a theorem entails that $\square X$ is a theorem.

Ted Sider's Logic for Philosophy would cover what you ask. I don't know if you can get a free pdf for it online. Also see these lectures from a course at the University of Oxford.

thank you very much
